# Writing Xml Scheme definition for a simple SOAP file

Tags: xml, soap, xsd

I tried to write a **.XSD** file to the xml file shown below which contain 2 namespaces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Envelope 
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate/Input" >
  <ns1:Body>
    <ns2:ConversionRate 
      xmlns:ns2="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
     <ns2:FromCurrency>USD</ns2:FromCurrency>
     <ns2:ToCurrency>USD</ns2:ToCurrency>
    </ns2:ConversionRate>
  </ns1:Body>
</ns1:Envelope>
```

I wrote two xml schemes to define this xml file

first one (**Envelope.xsd**)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate/Input"
  xmlns:ns2="http://www.webserviceX.NET/"
  targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate/Input">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/" 
    schemaLocation="C:\Documents and Settings\RoGulk\Desktop\SPM\ConversionRate.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="Body">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ns2:ConversionRate"/>  
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Envelope">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:Body"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And the **ConversionRate.xsd (inner XSD)** looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <xs:element name="ConversionRate">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FromCurrency" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="ToCurrency" type="xs:string"/>  
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>  
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But the problem is I cant validate above xml against these scheme definition.

Does any body know what the issue is?
thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to specify that the local elements declared in the schema document ConversionRate.xsd are in the ns2 namespace.  The simplest way to do so is to add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` on the `xs:schema` element; an alternative way is to specify `form="qualified"` on the element declarations for `FromCurrency` and `ToCurrency`.

Why?

Some schema authors feel strongly that local elements should behave like local attributes, and have unqualified names; others feel equally strongly that all elements declared in a schema document for a particular namespace should be in that namespace.  The working group developing XSD 1.0 fought over it bitterly for a couple of months (you can still make old XSD WG members pale by whispering "issue 208!" at them), and then compromised by handing the decision over to the schema author.  The unqualified party won the coin toss, and the default value of the `elementFormDefault` attribute was made `unqualified`.  This saves trouble for people who want local elements unqualified, and it means that people like you, who expect them to be qualified, need to make `elementFormDefault="qualified"` part of your standard schema-document template.